# How to reproduce following POC of dom based open redirection Vulnerability Flagged by burp suite scan

Tags: web-application, burp-suite, bug-bounty

During scan, the burp suite flagged DOM open redirection vulnerability with the following POC. How can I reproduce it?

Data is read from document.referrer and passed to xhr.send.
The following value was injected into the source:

```
https://www.example.com/package.json?cwvqen3b7s=cwvqen3b7s%27%22%60'%22/cwvqen3b7s/%3E%3Ccwvqen3b7s/\%3Ez7ib0ex4ig&
```

The previous value reached the sink as:

```
{"event_type":"web_events","data":{"user":{"location":{"city":"","country":"","ip":"","region":"","longitude":"","latitude":""},"device_id":"y0bptoge4y%2527%2522`'\"/y0bptoge4y/><y0bptoge4y/\\>y1uhp1763j&","group_id":"","user_id":"","city":"","country":"","ip":"","region":"","location_lng":"","location_lat":"","device_family":"Windows","device_model":"Windows","device_type":"Windows","os":"Windows","os_name":"Windows","os_version":"Windows","browser":"Chrome","browser_version":"106","platform":"Web","vwo":{}},"event_name":"ClickedOnFooter","team":"wordpress","url":"https://www.example.com///package.json//cizfq1z7xu%27%22%60'%22/cizfq1z7xu/%3E%3Ccizfq1z7xu//%3Emh8mnfzedc&","referrer":"https://www.example.com/package.json?cwvqen3b7s=cwvqen3b7s%27%22%60'%22/cwvqen3b7s/%3E%3Ccwvqen3b7s/\\%3Ez7ib0ex4ig&","referrerHostname":"www.example.com","value":"Twitter","group":"Social"},"api_key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

The stack trace at the source was:

```
at Object.ezDZK (<anonymous>:1:155875) at Object.QrWlV (<anonymous>:1:371064) at HTMLDocument.get [as referrer] (<anonymous>:1:372978) at Object.logEvent (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/themes/example/js/dist/bstack-load-scripts.js?v=1659000872:1:3699) at Arguments.<anonymous> (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/cache/js/bstack_1888b7a7ceb261d03e1c7270a137f0d7.js?v=1664863482:2:18517) at <anonymous>:1:714415 at Object.e [as logEvent] (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/cache/js/bstack_1888b7a7ceb261d03e1c7270a137f0d7.js?v=1664863482:2:18457) at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/themes/example/js/dist/bstack-load-scripts.js?v=1659000872:1:18968) at _0x2c55d2 (<anonymous>:1:244861) at Object.KYAOP (<anonymous>:1:104816) at _0x191273 (<anonymous>:1:247912) at Object.wtRYA (<anonymous>:1:220543) at _0x4f7f04 (<anonymous>:1:790364)
```

The stack trace at the sink was:

```
at Object.ZzNWK (<anonymous>:1:214066) at Object.ZBEoB (<anonymous>:1:755999) at _0xb65e0a (<anonymous>:1:771937) at Object.NhwKh (<anonymous>:1:662147) at _0x3c3c39.<computed>.<computed> [as send] (<anonymous>:1:666731) at Object.ajax (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/cache/js/bstack_1888b7a7ceb261d03e1c7270a137f0d7.js?v=1664863482:1:2770) at Object.logEvent (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/themes/example/js/dist/bstack-load-scripts.js?v=1659000872:1:3853) at Arguments.<anonymous> (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/cache/js/bstack_1888b7a7ceb261d03e1c7270a137f0d7.js?v=1664863482:2:18517) at <anonymous>:1:714415 at Object.e [as logEvent] (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/cache/js/bstack_1888b7a7ceb261d03e1c7270a137f0d7.js?v=1664863482:2:18457) at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (https://example.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/themes/example/js/dist/bstack-load-scripts.js?v=1659000872:1:18968) at _0x2c55d2 (<anonymous>:1:244861) at Object.KYAOP (<anonymous>:1:104816) at _0x191273 (<anonymous>:1:247912) at Object.wtRYA (<anonymous>:1:220543) at _0x4f7f04 (<anonymous>:1:790364)
```

This was triggered by a click event with the following HTML:

```
<a class="social-link custom-btn-amp-events" href="https://twitter.com/example" target="_blank"
```

The following proof of concept was generated for this issue:

```
<!-- Visit from your domain --> http://your-domain? <!-- Link back to site from your domain --> <a href="https://www.example.com/package.json">PoC</a>
```